# UITapGestureRecognizer EXC_BAD_ACCESS in self-contained UIView subclass

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiview, exc-bad-access, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've used UITapGestureRecognizer tons of times, but in this case I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when a tap occurs. I think it has to do with the fact that I'm adding it to an Alert-type overlay view. And for some reason the overlay view isn't getting retained even though it's on-screen.

I'm creating the view like this:

```
HelperView *testHelper = [HelperView helperWithBodyText:@"test text"];
[testHelper presentAtPoint:screenCenter];
```

The convenience method in HelperView.m looks like this:

```
+ (id)helperWithBodyText:(NSString*)text
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero bodyText:text];
}
```

And the rest of the code looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.container = [[AGWindowView alloc] initAndAddToKeyWindow];
        self.container.supportedInterfaceOrientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;

        self.overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
        self.overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.overlay.alpha = 0.6;
        [self.container addSubviewAndFillBounds:self.overlay]; //this fills the screen with a transparent red color, for testing

        UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissMe:)];
        [self.overlay addGestureRecognizer:tap]; //I want to dismiss the whole view if the overlay is tapped

        self.content = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame bodyText:(NSString*)bodyText
{
    self = [self initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        //TEST frame
        self.content.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 217, 134);

        // Initialization code
        UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"helper-bg"]
                                resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 28, 20, 20)];
        UIImageView *bgImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
        bgImgView.bounds = self.content.frame;
        [self.content addSubview:bgImgView];

}
    return self;
}

- (void)presentAtPoint:(CGPoint)loc
{
    CGPoint newPoint = [self.container convertPoint:loc toView:self.container];

    self.content.center = newPoint;
    [self.container addSubview:self.content];

}


- (void)dismissMe:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    //this never happens - I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when I tap the overlay
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HelperView is not the view getting displayed and it's not getting retained, but you're using as the target for the gesture recognizer. The AGWindowView property "container" is getting displayed and retained by its superview. Your code needs refactoring since you have this view HelperView that doesn't ever display anything itself, but if you want it to work like this you need to retain HelperView so it doesn't automatically get released. You can do this by assigning it to a strong instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's what I figured. But I want this HelperView to be created whenever I need it, and I don't want every view controller to require having a strong instance variable for it. For example a UIAlertView doesn't require a strong instance variable. How can I retain a self-contained view?

Comment: Another example is this: https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView. I've looked at the code but I can't tell how it gets retained.

Comment: Change `[self.container addSubview:self.content]` to be `[self.container addSubview:self]` and you will be fine, except the memory leak.

Comment: Make `HelperView` a subclass of `AGWindowView`. Remove the `container` property and just add all subviews to `self`. In your initializer change   `self = [super initWithFrame:frame];` to `self = [super initAndAddToKeyWindow];`